# How was immigration from Latin America handled before the passage of the Immigration & Nationality act of 1965?

Tags: united-states, immigration, population, civil-rights

I know that in the United States, before the passage of the [Immigration & Nationality act of 1965](https://history.house.gov/Historical-Highlights/1951-2000/Immigration-and-Nationality-Act-of-1965/), immigration was controlled by the [Immigration Act of 1924](https://history.house.gov/Historical-Highlights/1901-1950/The-Immigration-Act-of-1924/).

> It limited the number of immigrants that could be admitted to the U.S. to two percent of the total number of individuals from each nationality that resided in the United States in 1890—before waves of Slavic and Italian immigrants arrived in America. Despite vigorous protests from Japanese diplomats, the measure also excluded Japanese immigrants (a ban that would not be lifted until 1952). Finally, it allowed no more than 150,000 total immigrants who fell within the parameters of the quota system to enter the U.S. in any one year. After Senate passage, the Immigration Act was signed into law in late May 1924. *[History.house.gov](https://history.house.gov/Historical-Highlights/1901-1950/The-Immigration-Act-of-1924/)*

This law set restrictive quotas on the numbers of immigrants that were allowed to enter the country and it based this number on results from the 1890 census. However, it only set quotas for countries outside of the Americas. How was immigration from a country like Colombia controlled? With the exception of Mexico, which shares a border with the US, there are no old Latino immigrant communities. Immigrant communities from South America are fairly recent. Why is that?

Comment: A small comment: this website has an international audience and it would be helpful to state which country (USA) you are talking about earlier than the last line.  For instance the Immigration Act 1971 would confuse you, it is a British Act of Parliament!

Comment: @Martin Sorry about that. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Good question.  This will help to reconcile competing historical narratives. Upvote.. Working purely from memory, [Malcom Gladwell](https://www.pushkin.fm/episode/general-chapmans-last-stand/) suggested that there was no immigration control to Latin America at that time.

Comment: @MCW then how were they kept out? Because there was something that kept immigrants from almost every country in South America from immigrating to the US before the 1965 act.

Comment: See prior two comments..... that's why they are comments and not an answer.  IIRC, Gladwell says that they didn't need to be kept out - they came to the US to work and then returned home to their families (until our immigration policies made that impossible).  But I'm not pretending that my memory of a three year old source is perfect. that's why I provided the source and identified this as an opportunity to reconcile competing narratives.

Comment: That's a pretty gigantic "exception". Like 500 million acres worth, or 3/4 of a million square miles of (somewhat) populated former Mexican territory. (Also not really "immigrant" if the nation moved out from under them)

Comment: One might want to consider that various Latin American countries were themselves attractive *targets* of immigration in the relevant time frame. Examples: Current pope: son of Italian immigrants to Argentina; Fidel Castro: son of a Spanish immigrant to Cuba; Alberto Fujimori: son of Japanese immigrants to Peru. Hypothesis: Immigration "pressure" from Latin American counties was limited in the relevant time period, and [statistics](https://www.infoplease.com/us/society-culture/race/immigrants-us-country-origin) seem to confirm that. Potentially fewer racist (anti-Asian, anti-Semitic) aspects.

Comment: @njuffa I know that some countries in Latin America where themselves attracting immigrants. But they were also way more unstable. By 1965, Argentina was on its 4th military coupt and like its 6th sovereign debt default. Colombia had just ended a 10 year civil war in the mid 1950s and was just starting their conflict with the FARC, etc.

Comment: Further restrictions [contemplated](https://library.cqpress.com/cqresearcher/document.php?id=cqresrre1927081900) *Rep. John C. Box (Dem.) of Texas, author of a bill to limit immigration from Canada and Latin America which was introduced in 1925, has recently announced that he will re-introduce his bill during the forthcoming session. Harry E. Hull, Commissioner General of Immigration advocated extension of the quota system to countries of the Western Hemisphere in his report for the fiscal, year 1926 and is at present formulating recommendations of a similar nature to be presented to Congress*